# Show which build targets will be rebuilt if a specific file is updated

Tags: xcode, build-target

I have a large legacy C++ project whose build process drags in most of the build targets when individual files are updated, and consequently needlessly results in long build times.

To address this problem, I was looking for a way to check what build targets will be invoked when specific files from the project are touched.

With this in mind, does anyone know if xcode offers a way to visualize the dependency graph between the build targets of a project?